# Trigger para actualizar registro mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, trigger

Hola soy nuevo con los trigger y tengo un problema. Tengo una tabla con 2 campos |cantidad |criterio | y necesito que al momento de actualizar la cantidad el trigger actualice el criterio: ejemplo si actualizo la cantidad a > 0 entonces que criterio se actualice a Ganó, si cantidad = 0 entonces criterio que actualice a Perdió y si cantidad es vacío entonces criterio pase a pendiente.

```html
<?php
$id_mercado = $_POST['id_mercado'];
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$criterio = $_POST['criterio'];

$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE mercado SET cantidad='$cantidad',  criterio='$criterio' WHERE id_mercado=$id_mercado");
?>
```

el trigger que tengo es este

```html
CREATE TRIGGER estado_update BEFORE UPDATE ON mercado FOR EACH ROW BEGIN if new.cantidad > 0 then update mercado SET criterio = 'Ganó'; end if; END;
```

No he podido con el if anidado y no se como extructurar bien el código, el trigger lo cree en phpmyadmin, alguien me puede orientar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola para su caso debe de hacer el trigger de la siguiente manera.

```html
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER estado_update BEFORE UPDATE ON mercado FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.cantidad>0) THEN 
 SET NEW.criterio = 'Ganó'; 
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.cantidad=0) THEN
        SET NEW.criterio = 'Perdió';
    END IF;
     IF (NEW.cantidad ='') THEN 
        SET NEW.criterio = 'Pendiente'; 
    END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ok, voy hacer los cambios y le comento.

Comment: Gracias amigo me funcionó muchas gracias.